# How to use localized UIImage with specific language?

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, uiimage

I have settings in my App and want to give the user the possibility to switch the language of the app. The language can be different to the device setting.

For the NSStrings I found a solution but how can I do it with UIImages?

I've localized all my images but now they are chosen depending on the device language. What do I have to do to get this working? My only option that I have right now is to put the names in the Localizable.strings and load them from there.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thx ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

- `- [NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:localization:]`
- `- [NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:]`

should do it.

Then just use something like:

- `-[UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:]`
- `-[UIImage initWithData:]`

for creating a `UIImage`.

Comment: This looks very good and I think it should work but it doesn't. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but the method always returns nil for this: [[[NSBundle alloc] init] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"" forLocalization:@"en"];

Comment: @MoFuRo you need to use a designated initializer or convenience constructor provided by the class. In this case, `NSBundle` needs to know the path, url, or bundle id in order to return a valid bundle instance which is able to locate its resources. `+[NSBundle mainBundle]` returns your app's bundle, which is often what you want. So you could try this: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:.....`.

Comment: That looks much better but it doesn't add the en.proj to the path. This is the call: '[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:@"en"]'.

Comment: Maybe I will will append the .lproj to the language and use it as the subdirectory if this doesn't work.

Comment: yes, if the solution i posted does not work for some reason, you can create a bundle from a localization directory.